# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. Буквально сегодня начал учить Python и telebot API и не понимаю в чём проблемма

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, list, telebot

```
import telebot
TOKEN = 'тут есть токен, просто удалил его'
tb = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@tb.message_handlers(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    chatid = message.chat.id
    user_name = message.from_user.first_name
    ms = 'Привет ' + user_name
    tb.send_message(chatid, ms)

#tb.set_update_listener(start_message)
tb.infinity_polling()
```

[image]

Может у кого была такая ошибка?

Comment: ошибка говорит что объект не функция, попробуйте убрать s  (`@tb.message_handler`) вот статья с [примером](https://telegra.ph/Bot-01-13)

Answer (score 2):

Вместо

```
@tb.message_handlers(commands=['start'])
```

Напиши

```
@tb.message_handler(commands=['start'])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def telegram_bot(TOKEN):
     tb = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@tb.message_handlers(commands=['start'])
 def start_message(message):
    chatid = message.chat.id("Нпр Здраствуйте пишите тыры пыры по своему совершенствуй здесь")
```

Если не сработает, пробуй работать в Pycharm или VS code